# Can't launch gnome-control-center, fglrx problem?

Tags: debian, gnome-shell, fglrx

I have installed Debian yesterday. Later I installed the [AMD Catalyst Driver](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86_64) because the system didn't detected the second screen. It worked perfectly.

Now I can't launch `gnome-control-center`, I don't know if it's related to the AMD driver. Anyway it only displays these errors:

```
~> gnome-control-center
*** glibc detected *** gnome-control-center: free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fd97191ae88 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x76a16)[0x7fd98ea90a16]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6c)[0x7fd98ea957bc]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so(+0x1648e17)[0x7fd973b1ee17]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so(+0x163b4eb)[0x7fd973b114eb]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so(+0x1634005)[0x7fd973b0a005]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so(+0x163e02a)[0x7fd973b1402a]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so(+0x16ce2d2)[0x7fd973ba42d2]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so(+0x16cbc23)[0x7fd973ba1c23]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so(+0xf70320)[0x7fd973446320]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so(+0xf77472)[0x7fd97344d472]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so(+0xf77675)[0x7fd97344d675]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so(+0xe7895d)[0x7fd97334e95d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so(+0xe78c5a)[0x7fd97334ec5a]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so(+0xcbb057)[0x7fd973191057]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so(+0xbfc0b5)[0x7fd9730d20b5]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so(+0x34676c)[0x7fd97281c76c]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so(+0x10ff6bc)[0x7fd9735d56bc]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so(+0x1118138)[0x7fd9735ee138]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so(+0x111ff1d)[0x7fd9735f5f1d]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so(+0x1e4572e)[0x7fd97431b72e]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so(+0x1e44538)[0x7fd97431a538]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so(+0x1e39dc3)[0x7fd97430fdc3]
/usr/lib/libGL.so.1(+0x41935)[0x7fd97bda4935]
/usr/lib/libGL.so.1(glXCreateNewContext+0x71)[0x7fd97bda4e71]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.9(+0x649fa)[0x7fd9760249fa]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.9(cogl_display_setup+0x23)[0x7fd975fe2793]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.9(cogl_renderer_check_onscreen_template+0x69)[0x7fd975fe2019]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-1.0.so.0(+0x3405e)[0x7fd97648905e]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-1.0.so.0(+0x65259)[0x7fd9764ba259]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-1.0.so.0(+0x7c2b3)[0x7fd9764d12b3]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-1.0.so.0(+0x87cda)[0x7fd9764dccda]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-1.0.so.0(+0x87f0b)[0x7fd9764dcf0b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_option_context_parse+0x3b7)[0x7fd98f3525d7]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-1.0.so.0(clutter_init+0xd2)[0x7fd9764dd1d2]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcheese-gtk.so.21(cheese_gtk_init+0x24)[0x7fd97699ee34]
/usr/lib/control-center-1/panels/libuser-accounts.so(g_io_module_load+0x33)[0x7fd976bc3bc3]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0(+0x5e6a6)[0x7fd98f8a36a6]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_type_module_use+0x81)[0x7fd98f629a41]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0(g_io_modules_load_all_in_directory_with_scope+0x84)[0x7fd98f8a3a84]
gnome-control-center[0x40a9ca]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_type_create_instance+0x117)[0x7fd98f626a97]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(+0x16818)[0x7fd98f60b818]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_object_newv+0x781)[0x7fd98f60d2d1]
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0(g_object_new+0xec)[0x7fd98f60d91c]
gnome-control-center(main+0x72)[0x408d42]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x7fd98ea38ead]
gnome-control-center[0x408df1]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00413000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 812705                             /usr/bin/gnome-control-center
00612000-00613000 r--p 00012000 08:12 812705                             /usr/bin/gnome-control-center
00613000-00614000 rw-p 00013000 08:12 812705                             /usr/bin/gnome-control-center
01c03000-0228e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7fd96c000000-7fd96c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fd96c021000-7fd970000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fd971091000-7fd971093000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fd971093000-7fd971094000 rw-s 00000000 00:11 20534                      /run/shm/sem.__AMD_GL_CACHE__34a905d71ab77677_23
7fd971094000-7fd97115a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fd97115a000-7fd97185a000 rw-s 00006000 00:05 5546                       /dev/ati/card0
7fd97185a000-7fd97199b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fd97199b000-7fd97199c000 rw-s 00005000 00:05 5546                       /dev/ati/card0
7fd97199c000-7fd9719dc000 rw-s f7e00000 00:05 5546                       /dev/ati/card0
7fd9719dc000-7fd971a85000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 806915                     /usr/lib/libatiadlxx.so
7fd971a85000-7fd971b85000 ---p 000a9000 08:12 806915                     /usr/lib/libatiadlxx.so
7fd971b85000-7fd971b88000 rw-p 000a9000 08:12 806915                     /usr/lib/libatiadlxx.so
7fd971b88000-7fd971b98000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fd971bab000-7fd971bad000 rw-s 00002000 00:05 5546                       /dev/ati/card0
7fd971bad000-7fd971cc5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fd971cc5000-7fd971cc6000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fd971cc6000-7fd9724d6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fd9724d6000-7fd9746bf000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 806923                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so
7fd9746bf000-7fd9747be000 ---p 021e9000 08:12 806923                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so
7fd9747be000-7fd974976000 rwxp 021e8000 08:12 806923                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so
7fd974976000-7fd974aa6000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7fd974aa6000-7fd974aa7000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 796539                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
7fd974aa7000-7fd974ca6000 ---p 00001000 08:12 796539                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
7fd974ca6000-7fd974ca7000 rw-p 00000000 08:12 796539                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
7fd974ca7000-7fd974cac000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 799482                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-util.so.0.0.0
7fd974cac000-7fd974eac000 ---p 00005000 08:12 799482                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-util.so.0.0.0
7fd974eac000-7fd974ead000 rw-p 00005000 08:12 799482                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-util.so.0.0.0
7fd974ead000-7fd974eb5000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 799313                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libengine.so.0.0.0
7fd974eb5000-7fd9750b4000 ---p 00008000 08:12 799313                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libengine.so.0.0.0
7fd9750b4000-7fd9750b5000 r--p 00007000 08:12 799313                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libengine.so.0.0.0
7fd9750b5000-7fd9750b6000 rw-p 00008000 08:12 799313                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libengine.so.0.0.0
7fd9750b6000-7fd9750eb000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 799038                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsttag-0.10.so.0.25.0
7fd9750eb000-7fd9752ea000 ---p 00035000 08:12 799038                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsttag-0.10.so.0.25.0
7fd9752ea000-7fd9752ec000 r--p 00034000 08:12 799038                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsttag-0.10.so.0.25.0
7fd9752ec000-7fd9752ed000 rw-p 00036000 08:12 799038                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsttag-0.10.so.0.25.0
7fd9752ed000-7fd9752f6000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 799484                     /usr/lib/libstartup-notification-1.so.0.0.0
7fd9752f6000-7fd9754f5000 ---p 00009000 08:12 799484                     /usr/lib/libstartup-notification-1.so.0.0.0
7fd9754f5000-7fd9754f6000 rw-p 00008000 08:12 799484                     /usr/lib/libstartup-notification-1.so.0.0.0
7fd9754f6000-7fd9754fa000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 799312                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcluttergesture-0.0.2.so.0.0.0
7fd9754fa000-7fd9756f9000 ---p 00004000 08:12 799312                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcluttergesture-0.0.2.so.0.0.0
7fd9756f9000-7fd9756fa000 r--p 00003000 08:12 799312                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcluttergesture-0.0.2.so.0.0.0
7fd9756fa000-7fd9756fb000 rw-p 00004000 08:12 799312                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcluttergesture-0.0.2.so.0.0.0
7fd9756fb000-7fd975703000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 799310                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-imcontext-0.1.so.0.0.0
7fd975703000-7fd975902000 ---p 00008000 08:12 799310                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-imcontext-0.1.so.0.0.0
7fd975902000-7fd975903000 r--p 00007000 08:12 799310                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-imcontext-0.1.so.0.0.0
7fd975903000-7fd975904000 rw-p 00008000 08:12 799310                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-imcontext-0.1.so.0.0.0
7fd975904000-7fd975918000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 804064                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-gst-1.0.so.0.504.0
7fd975918000-7fd975b17000 ---p 00014000 08:12 804064                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-gst-1.0.so.0.504.0
7fd975b17000-7fd975b19000 rw-p 00013000 08:12 804064                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-gst-1.0.so.0.504.0
7fd975b19000-7fd975b24000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 797167                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-gtk-1.0.so.0.0.0
7fd975b24000-7fd975d24000 ---p 0000b000 08:12 797167                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-gtk-1.0.so.0.0.0
7fd975d24000-7fd975d25000 rw-p 0000b000 08:12 797167                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-gtk-1.0.so.0.0.0
7fd975d25000-7fd975dbc000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 799486                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmx-1.0.so.2.404.0
7fd975dbc000-7fd975fbc000 ---p 00097000 08:12 799486                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmx-1.0.so.2.404.0
7fd975fbc000-7fd975fbd000 r--p 00097000 08:12 799486                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmx-1.0.so.2.404.0
7fd975fbd000-7fd975fc0000 rw-p 00098000 08:12 799486                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmx-1.0.so.2.404.0
7fd975fc0000-7fd976047000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 796557                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.9.1.1
7fd976047000-7fd976247000 ---p 00087000 08:12 796557                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.9.1.1
7fd976247000-7fd97624b000 r--p 00087000 08:12 796557                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.9.1.1
7fd97624b000-7fd97624d000 rw-p 0008b000 08:12 796557                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl.so.9.1.1
7fd97624d000-7fd976254000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 796561                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl-pango.so.0.0.0
7fd976254000-7fd976453000 ---p 00007000 08:12 796561                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl-pango.so.0.0.0
7fd976453000-7fd976454000 r--p 00006000 08:12 796561                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl-pango.so.0.0.0
7fd976454000-7fd976455000 rw-p 00007000 08:12 796561                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcogl-pango.so.0.0.0
7fd976455000-7fd97657e000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 797161                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-1.0.so.0.1000.8
7fd97657e000-7fd97677e000 ---p 00129000 08:12 797161                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-1.0.so.0.1000.8
7fd97677e000-7fd976782000 r--p 00129000 08:12 797161                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-1.0.so.0.1000.8
7fd976782000-7fd976785000 rw-p 0012d000 08:12 797161                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclutter-1.0.so.0.1000.8
7fd976785000-7fd976786000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7fd976786000-7fd976795000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 804638                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcheese.so.3.2.5
7fd976795000-7fd976995000 ---p 0000f000 08:12 804638                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcheese.so.3.2.5
7fd976995000-7fd976996000 r--p 0000f000 08:12 804638                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcheese.so.3.2.5
7fd976996000-7fd976997000 rw-p 00010000 08:12 804638                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcheese.so.3.2.5
7fd976997000-7fd9769a3000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 804640                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcheese-gtk.so.21.1.5
7fd9769a3000-7fd976ba2000 ---p 0000c000 08:12 804640                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcheese-gtk.so.21.1.5
7fd976ba2000-7fd976ba3000 r--p 0000b000 08:12 804640                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcheese-gtk.so.21.1.5
7fd976ba3000-7fd976ba4000 rw-p 0000c000 08:12 804640                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcheese-gtk.so.21.1.5
7fd976ba4000-7fd976bcf000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 812874                     /usr/lib/control-center-1/panels/libuser-accounts.so
7fd976bcf000-7fd976dce000 ---p 0002b000 08:12 812874                     /usr/lib/control-center-1/panels/libuser-accounts.so
7fd976dce000-7fd976dcf000 r--p 0002a000 08:12 812874                     /usr/lib/control-center-1/panels/libuser-accounts.so
7fd976dcf000-7fd976dd1000 rw-p 0002b000 08:12 812874                     /usr/lib/control-center-1/panels/libuser-accounts.so
7fd976dd1000-7fd976dec000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 794063                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpolkit-gobject-1.so.0.0.0
7fd976dec000-7fd976feb000 ---p 0001b000 08:12 794063                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpolkit-gobject-1.so.0.0.0
7fd976feb000-7fd976fec000 r--p 0001a000 08:12 794063                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpolkit-gobject-1.so.0.0.0
7fd976fec000-7fd976fed000 rw-p 0001b000 08:12 794063                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpolkit-gobject-1.so.0.0.0
7fd976fed000-7fd976ffe000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 812869                     /usr/lib/control-center-1/panels/libdate_time.so
7fd976ffe000-7fd9771fe000 ---p 00011000 08:12 812869                     /usr/lib/control-center-1/panels/libdate_time.so
7fd9771fe000-7fd9771ff000 r--p 00011000 08:12 812869                     /usr/lib/control-center-1/panels/libdate_time.so
7fd9771ff000-7fd977200000 rw-p 00012000 08:12 812869                     /usr/lib/control-center-1/panels/libdate_time.so
7fd977200000-7fd977224000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 802194                     /usr/lib/libgnome-bluetooth.so.10.0.0
7fd977224000-7fd977424000 ---p 00024000 08:12 802194                     /usr/lib/libgnome-bluetooth.so.10.0.0
7fd977424000-7fd977426000 r--p 00024000 08:12 802194                     /usr/lib/libgnome-bluetooth.so.10.0.0
7fd977426000-7fd977427000 rw-p 00026000 08:12 802194                     /usr/lib/libgnome-bluetooth.so.10.0.0
7fd977427000-7fd97742e000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 812710                     /usr/lib/control-center-1/panels/libbluetooth.so
7fd97742e000-7fd97762d000 ---p 00007000 08:12 812710                     /usr/lib/control-center-1/panels/libbluetooth.so
7fd97762d000-7fd97762e000 r--p 00006000 08:12 812710                     /usr/lib/control-center-1/panels/libbluetooth.so
7fd97762e000-7fd97762f000 rw-p 00007000 08:12 812710                     /usr/lib/control-center-1/panels/libbluetooth.so
7fd97762f000-7fd977640000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 792338                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.0.0
7fd977640000-7fd97783f000 ---p 00011000 08:12 792338                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.0.0
7fd97783f000-7fd977840000 r--p 00010000 08:12 792338                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.0.0
7fd977840000-7fd977841000 rw-p 00011000 08:12 792338                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.0.0
7fd977841000-7fd977851000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 792340                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.3.1.16
7fd977851000-7fd977a50000 ---p 00010000 08:12 792340                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.3.1.16
7fd977a50000-7fd977a51000 r--p 0000f000 08:12 792340                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.3.1.16
7fd977a51000-7fd977a52000 rw-p 00010000 08:12 792340                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.3.1.16
7fd977a52000-7fd977a5b000 r-xp 00000000 08:12 794051                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgudev-1.0.so.0.1.1
7fd977a5b000-7fd977c5a000 ---p 00009000 08:12 794051                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgudev-1.0.so.0.1.1fish: Tâche 1, 'gnome-control-center' terminée par le signal SIGABRT (Abandon)
```

It returns a `SIGABRT` signal. I don't know what it means.

Comment: Installing all packages that have been removed *might* be possible with the following command (provided that all uninstalled packages are still in the "rc" state, I'm not too sure of that): `aptitude install '~c'`

Comment: You can also check `/var/log/dpkg.log` to see what packages exactly were removed.

Comment: @MartinvonWittich : it doesn't install anything, it seems that the commands in my question have already reinstalled the packages. @wurtel : thanks, I'm going to check each package with `grep remove /var/log/dpkg.log`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dependencies linking Debian packages ensure that you can't break one package by uninstalling others, unless you force things. So if the `gnome-control-center` package is still installed, that means that all its dependencies are still there too.

Given that the `fglrx` driver was installed from the binaries provided on AMD's web site, it doesn't have the same guarantee. If you can, I would suggest [uninstalling `fglrx`](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Catalyst-Linux-Installer-Notes.aspx#Uninstall) with `sh ./amd-driver-installer-[version]-x86.x86_64.run --uninstall` and verifying whether `gnome-control-center` works without it (using the `radeon` driver).

Once that's determined, you can reinstall `fglrx`, perhaps using the packages available alongside Debian in the `non-free` repositories (start from the [fglrx-driver](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/fglrx-driver) package; you may need to add `contrib`and `non-free`to the lines ending with `main` in `/etc/apt/sources.list`). Complete instructions are available on the [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/ATIProprietary).

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution for this problem here

http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=119637

It seems that the binary shipped from AMD is linked against another version of libc, and this breaks for some reason gnome-control-center (as it calls useraccounts and this seems to be dependent somehow (why???) of some GL libs.) This is of course purely a shot in the dark, but I think, it goes in that direction.

Using the debian package will probably not have this problem.